# Разработка Android-приложения со взаимодействием с акселерометром

Tags: java, android

Суть такова: устройство считывает информацию о датчиках акселерометра, и если пользователь начинает трясти телефон, приложение сигнализирует об этом.

Я понимаю, что, в принципе, это лёгкое задание, но я никак не могу понять, как написать этот злосчастный код.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5271532/5698593

Comment: Руками? Надиктовать? Конкретный то вопрос в чём? Как получить данные с акселерометра? Как их обработать? Как сигнализировать? Как определить что данные акселерометра соответствуют параметрам тряски?

Comment: Если надиктуете, буду благодарен. Конкретные вопросы - "как получить данные с акселерометра?" и "как их обработать?". Как сигнализировать - придумаю сам. Отвечая на последний вопрос, главное, чтобы они (параметры тряски) были, откалибровать уже можно самому.
Ссылку посмотрю, огромное спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Вот простой пример получения данных акселерометра: при изменении хотя бы одной координаты на значение `mOffset`, в `TextView` отображаются текущие значения координат:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener {

    private TextView mTextView;

    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private Sensor mAccelerometer;

    private double mX, mY, mZ;
    private final double mOffset = 0.1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view);

        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        Sensor mySensor = event.sensor;

        if (mySensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
            float x = event.values[0];
            float y = event.values[1];
            float z = event.values[2];

            if (Math.abs(x - mX) >= mOffset || Math.abs(y - mY) >= mOffset || Math.abs(z - mZ) >= mOffset) {
                mTextView.setText("x = " + x + "\ny = " + y + "\nz = " + z);
                mX = x;
                mY = y;
                mZ = z;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

    }

    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }

    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    }
}
```

Для определения *тряски* можно замерять изменение координат за определенные интервалы времени. Если за некоторый (*малый*) промежуток времени произошло изменение координат на какую-то определенную дельта, то *тряска* была.

Выше описан, разумеется, самый примитивный случай.